# 4 Quadrant DC chopper Operation

Tags: motor, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter, motor-controller, braking

can anyone explain 2nd quadrant operation of DC chopper in easy way? may i  ask about  how brake applied in 2nd quadrant
[image]

Comment: Context please - where does the picture come from?

Comment: i have downloaded a chapter from the internet. this is one of them

Comment: From where? Where's the link? Where's the attribution?

Comment: https://pjshahjalgaon.jimdofree.com/app/download/7859277554/UNIT5+Chopper.pdf?t=1569412729

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the first quadrant operation as being a buck converter down from the supply to the motor.

You can think of the second quadrant as being a boost converter from the motor's generated low voltage up to the supply voltage. This causes current generated by the motor to flow into the supply, braking the motor. The amount of braking can be chosen by controlling the current that is allowed to flow.

Comment: can u explain with circuit..?

Comment: @usman_aruz You've got the circuit in your OP. Look up [Boost Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) on wikipedia. It has far more description there than I have the motivation to type.